# Spring Webflow 2.3 Testing: How to mock @Autowired fields of a flow variable

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

There are clear guidelines for mocking Spring Beans used within a Spring Webflow flow. Flows can implicitly refer to Spring Beans from flows by default and AbstractXmlFlowExecutionTests base test class has a method to override to mock those beans.

I cannot find a similar means for mocking @Autowired fields of flow variables in the flow under test. See the following basic setup to see what I mean.

**Flow under test:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd"
      parent="commons">

    <var name="consumerBean" class="com.mycompany.ConsumerBean" />

        <!-- etc.. -->
```

**Bean with @Autowired fields:**

```
public class ConsumerBean implements Serializable {

    @Autowired
    transient CustomerService userService;

    //Etc..
```

So my question is, how do I provide/configure a mock of 'userService' to the 'consumerBean' flow variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Autowired fields of a flow variable are Spring Beans, so should be configured in the same place the Spring Beans accessed by the flow would be configured and mocked.

```
    // Setup mocks
    @Override
    protected void configureFlowBuilderContext(MockFlowBuilderContext builderContext) {

    builderContext.registerBean("consumerBean", mock(ConsumerBean.class));


    builderContext.registerBean("userService", mock(CustomerService.class));
    }
```